# Backbone.js router with multiple page app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Am trying to  use the backbone.js router with a multiple page application.
The router works fine with the default route i.e localhost e.g `"http://localhost:35970/"`
or www.myhompage.com" 
but I want to use the backbone router on a page with path such as:

```
"http://localhost:35970/customer/index"
```

so that the backbone routes can look like this"

```
"http://localhost:35970/customer/index#create"
```

but it does not seem to work this way, is there anything I am missing to make it work on such a path?

here is my code, thanks:

```
 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            "Contact/Create": "create"

        },
        create: function () {
            alert('router test');
        }
    });
```

//EDIT

Thanks everyone, this is what I was missing

```
root: "/customer/index/"
```

so therefore

```
Backbone.history.start({     pushState: true,     root: "/customer/index/" })
```

I started history without specifying that the root path wasnt the default path

```
Backbone.history.start({     pushState: true })
```

and hence the problem.

Comment: From backbone.js docs: "If your application is not being served from the root url / of your domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an option: `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"})`"

Answer (score 2):

From Backbone documentation:

> If your application is not being served from the root url / of your
>   domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an
>   option: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:
>   "/public/search/"})

So you should define which part of the url is the root. In your case:

```
Backbone.history.start({ 
    root: "/customer/index/"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your router, you need to create a new object, so you could try:

```
var app_router = new Router();
```

then you have to start it up, so do:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

You should be able to go to your routes now.

A backbone router is from a path to a function, so in your case, if you go to

```
http://localhost:35970/#Contact/Create
```

You should see 'router test'

Comment: thanks, I was also missing the root:'Customer/Create'                       Backbone.history.start({ 
    root: "/customer/index/"
})

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the root path, i.e.:

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true, 
    root: "/customer/index/"
})
```

See docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: He doesn't really need pushState, that would make things complicated.